# Youtube video not able show full screen in WKWebkit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, html5-video, wkwebview

I am getting youtube video urls from server. I just want to auto play once user selected them on tableview cell in next screen with autoplay.

So, I am using WKWebview and loading html string.

```
@IBOutlet weak var youtubeWebview: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.loadWebView()
}

func loadWebView() {
    var embedVideoHtml:String {
        return """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
        <div id="player"></div>

        <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '\(youtubeWebview.frame.height)',
        width: '\(youtubeWebview.frame.width)',
        videoId: '\(videoLinkId)',
        events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
        });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
    }
    if !self.didLoadVideo {
        self.didLoadVideo = true
        self.youtubeWebview.loadHTMLString(embedVideoHtml, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

But, The problem is it's showing 1/4 of the entire screen. It is not showing as expected size. I am expecting the video size should be as WKWebview.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626173/how-to-autoplay-youtube-video-in-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML will be loaded as a normal Webpage. This means that any layout issues should be solved in that context. The assumption that it will be fullscreen by itself is not helping you. I would suggest doing it with css.